# How to show that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr\mathbb{Z}_3$ is not nilpotent?

Tags: group-theory, wreath-product

There's a Theorem by G.Baumslag (https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/92AE6ED711DC037B81E8AC3C30AEE145/S0305004100033934a.pdf/div-class-title-wreath-products-and-span-class-italic-p-span-groups-div.pdf) that says that Wreath Products $A\wr B$are nilpotent if and only if A and B are $p$-groups for the same prime $p$, $B$ finite and $A$ of finite exponent. Clearly, $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}_3$ doesn't satisfy these conditions, so how can I show that it isn't nilpotent? I tried to find a subgroup that wasn't nilpotent and struggled. Thank you

Comment: If it is nilpotent then it is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: So prove that it has more than one Sylow $3$-subgroup.

Comment: Is there a reference for that Soloveichik? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @FozzyBear217 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group

Comment: @DerekHolt It only has one sylow-3 subgroup, what do i do now?

Comment: No, it has four Sylow $3$-subgroups.